# Forcing linking through the PLT

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, clang

I just did a quick benchmark of the PLT overhead, and I found I'm unable to force my functions to go through the PLT in the final executable unless I put the code in a shared library and link that.

Example build script:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
cat > main.c <<EOF
void fn(void);
void fn_H(void);
int main(int C, char **V){
    if(C>1){
        for(int i=100000000; i--; ) fn();
    }else{
        for(int i=100000000; i--; ) fn_H();
    }
}
EOF

cat > fn.c <<EOF
void fn(void){}
__typeof(fn) fn_H __attribute((alias("fn"),visibility("hidden")));
EOF

: ${CC:=gcc}
$CC main.c fn.c -Os -fpic -shared -o lib.so && $CC $PWD/lib.so && time ./a.out 1
$CC main.c fn.c -fpie -fpic -fplt -rdynamic -pie -Os  && time ./a.out 1 # no PLT :(
```

The first of the last 2 build lines (which uses a dynamic lib) does make the `fn`-call go through the PLT and this shows in both the greater execution time and in `objdump` output.
The second line links `fn` directly (despite me throwing a whole bunch of options at it some of which I thought would help in making it go through the PLT) (both the smaller runtime and objdump output show this).

Tried it on Linux with gcc and clang -- same results.

My question is: Is it possible to force PLT linking without using a shared library?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler and linker will only use the PLT when the ABI absolutely requires them to..because of the heavy overhead it has. much work has been done to avoid it. Usually it is only used to call routines on position independant shared libraries.